# How to find if message is already printed to the console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

Assume I run my Javascript project in a browser and I'm inside a specific module, can I check whether is **already** message printed to the console ? i.e. read message from the console...

For example I'm inside my js.file inside function want to check if already printed hello world in the console.

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Comment: Do you print the message yourself, or you are expecting some other code to print it?

Comment: In any case, I wouldn't rely on the console output to store state. Maybe you can raise a flag when you are printing "hello world" and check the flag wherever you need it.

Comment: @OctavZlatior - no the message is printed not by myself, but I know this specific message

Comment: You might want to check for something else the code is doing besides printing the message. Can you provide the code that is printing the message?
As a side note, I think the console implementation is platform-specific. They are probably similar on Chrome and Firefox, but I think it does not even exist on Internet Explorer (if memory serves me well)...

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jthanto's answer gave me an idea. I don't think it's good practice, but if you must, you can define your own console class:

```
var MyConsole = function(oldConsole) {
    // store all messages ever logged
    this.log = [];
    // keep a pointer to oldConsole
    this.oldConsole = oldConsole;
}

MyConsole.prototype.log = function(args) {
    // push the message into log
    this.log.push(Array.prototype.join.call(args));
    // call oldConsole.log to actually display the message on the console
    if (this.oldConsole)
        this.oldConsole.log.apply(this.oldConsole, args);
}

// TODO: implement all other console methods in this fashion (apply for all console API methods)
MyConsole.prototype.<method> = function(args) {
    if (this.oldConsole)
        this.oldConsole.<method>.apply(this.oldConsole, args);
}

// method to check if something was printed
MyConsole.prototype.wasLogged(message) {
    return this.log.indexOf(message)!==-1;
}

// replace console with an instance of MyConsole, pointing to the old console
console = new MyConsole(console);
```

Save it in a file and load it first (right at the top of your  tags)

Use it like:

```
if (console.wasLogged("Hello World"))
    doStuffz();
```

Hope it helps. Mind it's not tested, but should give you some pointers :)

Comment: Good thing this is cross-browser compatible. Even more, it would work even in browser which don't have a console implementation :)

Comment: Also, you don't have to change other code... Whenever somebody calls console.log() it would store it in your log array

Answer (score 1):

You could always define your own function for "console.logging" one or more messages (if this is what you are doing), and have a boolean in this function to handle this sort of thing.

I would bet it's not "best practice", but it would solve your problem in some degree.

```
var messageSent = false;
    var myConsoleLog = function($strMessage){
        if (!messageSent) {
            console.log($strMessage);
            messageSent = true;
        } else {
            // Do whatever you feel like
        }
    };
```

Of course if you need to check for more cases you will need to alter the function to actually keep track of more messages. :)

Comment: This might be an interesting idea... I wonder if you can overwrite the console object in a global, something like "var console = new MyConsole()", and define overrides for console.log and all the other console methods.

Comment: As the other answer mentions, it can probably be done. I for one would not recommend it. But it might be I just don't see the functional value of doing it. It might actually be perfect for your project, if you are doing some serverside stuff with only logging to terminal or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally it can't be done. Look at Chrome console's API:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api

But this experimental Chrome feature can solve your problem: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental_devtools_console

Unfortunately it looks like other browsers doesn't have tools like this.